# The table 'flag'

Tags: magento2, database

In Magento 2 there is a table called `flag`.
The table is created `Magento\Setup\Model\Installer`.
What does this table do / hold?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Magento* components uses this table as **key-values storage** for any data, if creation additional table is overhead. But many developers doesn't know about this functionality and uses `config` or special custom tables for such data.

You can find all usages of this table using search among childs of `\Magento\Framework\Flag` class.

Moreover, this functionality available beginning from *Magento 1*.

*For example:*

Your module creates additional attribute set in InstallData, but you need to store attribute set id for usage in future.

Comment: So basically, If I need one value stored for something I can store it here? For example to know the last time a script was executed.

Comment: @Marius yes. Look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/fd8dcad31804c674eb8ca177b59f105819771fd0/app/code/Magento/Analytics/Cron/SignUp.php#L76 for example

Comment: Here is a Magento Community article with good instructions: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-store-variables-for-later-use/td-p/477880